# Least Squares with constraints

Tags: r, constraints

I would like to run a polynomial least-squares regression using Bernstein polynomials. 
According to Wang and Ghosh (2012), these kinds of polynomials can be constrained to be monotone decreasing and convex by adding the following constraint to the regression:

[image]

I estimate the regression using limSolve following the example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220614/linear-regression-polynomial-slope-constraint-in-r).
This is my code so far:

```
hr <- c(9.0, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 13.5, 14.0, 14.5, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0,
        16.5, 17.0, 17.5, 18.0, 18.5, 19.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5,
        24.0, 24.5, 25.0, 25.5, 26.0, 26.5, 27.0, 27.5, 28.0, 28.5, 29.0, 29.5, 30.0, 30.5, 31.0,
        31.5, 32.0, 32.5, 33.0, 33.5, 34.0, 34.5, 35.0, 35.5, 36.0, 36.5, 37.0, 37.5, 38.0, 38.5,
        39.0, 39.5)
fq <- c( 305, 310, 303, 236, 266, 241, 268, 222, 235, 230, 189, 191, 193, 162, 184, 170, 145, 147, 165,
         142, 155, 158, 130, 135, 122, 125, 126, 131, 117, 109, 112, 122, 104, 101, 76, 102, 97, 82,
         78,  78,  62,  96,  77,  73,  71,  81,  86,  85, 81, 68, 64, 73, 69, 53,  61, 66, 54,
         55,  46,  53,  48,  65)

dat <- data.frame(hr=hr, fq=fq)

b0 <- (1-hr)^4
b1 <- 4*hr*(1-hr)^3
b2 <- 6*hr^2*(1-hr)^2
b3 <- 4*hr^3*(1-hr)
b4 <- hr^4

library(Matrix)
library(limSolve)
A <- cbind(b0, b1, b2, b3, b4)
b <- fq
G <- matrix(nrow=4, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE, data = c(-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                   1, -2, 1, 0, 0,
                                                   0, 1, -2, 1, 0,
                                                   0, 0, 1, -2, 1))

h <- rep(0,4)
B_c <- lsei(A = A, B = b, G = G, H = h, type=2)

# predictions:
my_predict <- function(hr,coefficients){
  X <- cbind(cbind(b0, b1, b2, b3, b4))
  predictions <- X%*%coefficients
}

# compute predictions 
xpred <- seq(0,1,len=62)
dat$pred <- my_predict(xpred,B_c$X)


# plot results
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = hr, y = fq)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = hr, y = pred, color = "constrained fit"))
p
```

This runs well, but the predicted curve is not monotone or convex. So there must be something wrong. [image]

## EDIT:

I've tried to run the same regression using least-squares without the constraint. The coefficients of the two regressions (1. w/o constraints, 2. w/constraints) seem very different. Is it possible that the constraints are partly working but not fully?

```
# without the constraint:
X <- cbind(b0, b1, b2, b3, b4)
B<- lm(fq ~ X, data=dat)

coefs <- cbind(B_c$X, B$coefficients)
```

Comment: The values in your `xpred` variable do not participate in the calculations inside the `my_predict()` function. Are you sure the `X` is set up correctly ?

Comment: You might be right, that there is something wrong there. But if I change it to this ```X <- cbind(b0, b1, b2, b3, b4)  dat$pred <- X%*%B_c$X``` to estimate the predicted values, I am essentially doing the same thing. Right?  My shape constraint on the coefficient is still not binding. So something else must also be going on. Probably in the regression?